# String [] words = s.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");

Tags: java, string

What does it mean "**[^a-zA-Z]+**" ?

I am a beginner in JAVA and not getting what does it mean .

Comment: Hello. Have a look at regular expressions. For example: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html (found on google searching for "java regular expression")

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) clearly state that the `split` method accepts a regular expression, with a link to tell you the syntax. There is tons of online material if you still don't understand from googling "regular expressions java".

Comment: and here the official documentation [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) - despite the other sources probably being better to start with - and be aware that split returns the parts that did not match the regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means split the string on sequences of one or more consecutive non-letters.
Study https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Eg. if `s="abc, zzz!,ccc=ddd0eee"`
then words = `{"abc", "zzz", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"}`

Answer (score 0):

It's called `RegEx` , or **Regular Expression** , which defines a search pattern into a `String`.

You can find a good tutorial with examples [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's regular expression. This one mean "match all strings that contain a non-letter". Also you can learn regex https://www.marksanborn.net/howto/learning-regular-expressions-for-beginners-the-basics/